# HTML5 Canvas animate line from point A to point B

Tags: html, canvas, line

I am building an animation with HTML5 canvas, I'm very new to the language so am learning on the go a little bit.

The animation is to be lines "drawing" from point A to point B to point C to point D etc (13 lines in total).

I have been able to draw the lines with this code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="220" height="600"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 2);
    // LINE 1
    context.lineTo(220, 2);
    // LINE 2
    context.lineTo(0, 30);
    // LINE 3
    context.lineTo(220, 30);
    // LINE 4
    context.lineTo(0, 60);
    // LINE 5
    context.lineTo(220, 60);
    // LINE 6
    context.lineTo(0, 90);
    // LINE 7
    context.lineTo(220, 90);
    // LINE 8
    context.lineTo(0, 120);
    // LINE 9
    context.lineTo(220, 120);
    // LINE 10
    context.lineTo(0, 150);
    // LINE 11
    context.lineTo(220, 150);
    // LINE 12
    context.lineTo(0, 180);
    // LINE 13
    context.lineTo(220, 180);


    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.stroke();
</script>
```

However, now I want to be able to animate the lines one by one. Can anybody help me figure out how I would do this please?

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zv7jgo4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6zv7jgo4/1/ 
and this one for clearing after X lines:
http://jsfiddle.net/6zv7jgo4/2/

Use a function to draw the lines, like this:

```
function drawLine(whichOne, context)
{
    context.beginPath();

    if (whichOne % 2 == 0)
    {
        context.moveTo(0,2 + (whichOne / 2) * 30);
        context.lineTo(220, 2 + ((whichOne + 1) / 2) * 30);
    }
    else
    {
        context.moveTo(220,2 + (whichOne / 2) * 30);
        context.lineTo(0, 2 + ((whichOne + 1) / 2) * 30);
    }
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.stroke();

}
```

The function automatically calculates where it should draw, depending on which line you want it to draw.

Then you just use an interval to draw the lines one by one:

```
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function(){

      if (counter > 1000000) {//or any other number
          counter = 0;
          context.clearRect(0, 0, 220, 600);
      }


      drawLine(counter,context);
      counter++;



},1000);
```

Full code: see jsfiddle!

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks so much. Is there a way to limit the amount of lines created so it doesn't create them infinitely?

Comment: Of course there is. updated code coming in 2 minutes!

Comment: @SamSkirrow Updated my code and the fiddle. Have fun with it!

Comment: Getting on great with this code you helped with. Can you think how I might make it random between any of the points?

Comment: What do you mean by random? Can you give more information? If you want, you can also contact me in the SO-chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75113/discussion-between-sam-skirrow-and-jordumus).

Answer (score 1):

Use context.stroke() after each context.lineTo() and add a small delay after each context.stroke().

Maybe you can do a function:

```
function drawLine(x, y) {
     context.lineTo(x, y);
     context.stroke();
}
```

Then do:

```
drawLine(220, 2);
setTimeout(function () {
       drawLine(0, 30);
}, 200);
setTimeout(function () {
      drawLine(220, 30);
}, 200);
....
```

Edit:

Also make sure you initialise the context strokewidth in the beginning.

Comment: You're forgetting the `moveTo` part: with your code, each line will start at the same point.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misinterpreted your code. You're right, it would work, but it would also contain quite a lot of repetitive code.

Comment: I assumed that the pattern may not always be so predictable.